# BIOS gives one only boot option -- ubuntu

Tags: boot

I installed 20.04 0n Aspire 5. Now, I need to run windows sometimes, so I created bootable flash drive with windows 10 and discovered that BIOS doesn't give any boot options but ubuntu itself.

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Hi oldfred. The link is: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Ycp6pyR3BH/ But the app didn't ask what system I wanted to check out.

Comment: You only show Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. And if no other system found, it will not normally show grub menu. Windows does not boot from USB drives as it is licensed for one system only. And I thought Windows only booted from NTFS, not exFAT?

Comment: I downloaded an ISO image of Windows 10 from their site. I hoped that entailed possibility to make a bootable USB? As for the file system -- I followed an instruction of a third party. Should I try to remake it with NTFS?